# cite package in a beamerposter

Tags: citing, beamerposter, posters, cite-package

Is there a problem with using the cite package within a beamerposter?  I'm trying to use it so that my references are ordered when I call \cite{ref1,ref2,ref3}, but I get the error:

```
./main.tex:333: Undefined control sequence.
\@cite@n ...mpcnta \m@ne \mathchardef \@cite@incr 
                                                  \z@ \let \@h@ld \@empty \l...
```

This is a sample source file which will generate the error.  To test this, you will need to input your own .bib file with the appropriate references.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{TEST} % Poster title

\author{AUTHOR}
\institute{INSTITUTE}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations


\begin{frame}[t] 

  \begin{columns}[t]

    \begin{column}{\onecolwid} % The first column



      \begin{block}{Block}

        CITATIONS \cite{ref1,ref2}.  
      \end{block}


      \begin{block}{References}
        \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
        \bibliography{bibfile}

      \end{block}


    \end{column} 

  \end{columns} 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is it simply not possible to use the cite package with the beamerposter?  Is there an alternative?

Comment: Please post not only the error message but a minimal example that gives rise to the error.

Comment: Use `\cite{article-full,book-full}` and `\bibliography{xampl}`, then everyone will be able to run your example directly (`xampl.bib` is included with BibTeX, I believe).

Comment: Works fine if I insert some dummy citations from my .bib file. Please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: Does it work with `\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}` instead of `\usepackage{cite}`? (@samcarter Hm, I could reproduce the error.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Interesting!  I used the following code https://pastebin.com/gqBeqrcU with pdflatex without problems.

Comment: @samcarter That also throws an error here. (Didn't mention it, but it only occurs on the second run of `pdflatex` after `bibtex`, i.e. when citations are resolved, but that was perhaps obvious.) I'm still on TL16 though, if you're on TL17 perhaps something has changed.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'm on TL17 - maybe that's the difference. Both runs are error free for me.

Comment: @user2379888 Which tex distribution do you use?

Comment: I have had this same error with TL17 (via MacPorts) and on Overleaf.  I also got the same error using @TorbjørnT's example.

Comment: Which example of mine are you referring to? Using `natbib`? If yes, did you delete the `.aux` and `.bib` file first? Because that works fine both here and on Overleaf.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant the pastebin example of @samcarter

Comment: @user2379888 In case you'd like to compare package versions, here are the ones I use: https://pastebin.com/hqz9tyb4

Comment: @samcarter, is there any easy way to get my system to spit out the packages/versions?

Comment: Yes, place `\listfiles` before `\begin{document}`, compile and have a look into your `.log` file - there you will find the list under `*File List*`

Comment: @samcarter, posted it here: https://pastebin.com/CUcQCCmV, also the suggestion of using natbib worked.

Comment: @user2379888 Seems that some of your packages are not the current version - in case you are not satisfied with the natbib solution, updating may be worth a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error does not occur with an up-to-date TeX Live 2017, so some of your packages appear to be outdated. If updating is not an option, an alternative to `\usepackage{cite}` is

```
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
```